# use IF statment in AWK

Tags: linux, bash, awk, variable

i'm working on big script and i'm stucking in this part, if anyone can help me please

this is the file sample

```
31:49.9,9.92,TCP ,1_19,490,EXT_SERVER,22,5,257,1,.ASF,0,normal
```

and this is the part of my script

```
read -p "Please input the function itself ex, > : " function
read -p "Please input the value: " value
```

if i used like this, working fine with me

```
cat temp | awk -F',' -v val="$value" '{if($8 > val) print $0}' > $destfile
```

but when i try use like this

```
cat temp | awk -F',' -v val="$value" -v fn="$function" '{if($8 fn val) print $0}' > $destfile
```

Thanks

Comment: FYI `'{if($8 > val) print $0}'` can be written as just `'$8 > val'`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not many programming languages allow producing an operator from the contents of a variable at runtime. When the code is parsed, the expression in the condition of the if-statement has to be syntactically valid, and `$number variable variable` isn't.

(Of course in the shell and `test`/`[` you could do e.g. `[ "$a" "$op" "$b" ]`, but that's because `[` is a command, and parses its arguments after the shell has expanded the variables.)

You have some options.

You could have the shell expand the operator before awk parses the code, so something like this:

```
cat temp | awk -F',' -v val="$value" '
               {if($8 '"$function"' val) print $0}' > $destfile
```

then if `$function` contained e.g. `<`, awk would see `{if($8 < val) ...`. If you do this, you SHOULD verify that `$function` is an acceptable operator before running awk. Otherwise your users could get surprising syntax errors, or worse.

---

As another alternative, you could have the user enter both a lower and upper limit, and check both in the code, always. Substitute e.g. `-inf`/`+inf` or some other sufficiently low/high values if the user doesn't want to enter a lower/upper limit respectively.

```
read -p "Please enter lower limit: " lo
read -p "Please enter upper limit: " hi
cat temp | awk -F',' -v lo="${lo:--inf}" -v hi="${hi:-+inf}" '
               {if (lo <= $8 && $8 <= hi) print $0}' > $destfile
```

(`-inf`/`+inf` seem to work directly in GNU awk and Busybox, mawk appears to require forcing them to numbers with `lo + 0 <= $8` etc.)

---

I suppose in GNU awk a third choice would be making functions for all different comparison operators you want to provide, and then using [indirect function calls](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Indirect-Calls.html) to call one of them, based on a name given in a variable.

E.g. for less-than and greater-than tests:

```
read -p "Please input the function (lt or gt): " op
read -p "Please input the value: " value
cat temp | gawk -F',' -v op="$op" -v val="$value" '
                function lt(a, b) { return a < b; }
                function gt(a, b) { return a > b; }
                {if (@op($8, val)) print $0}'
```

The downside of this is of course that you'll have to explicitly create *all* the functions, and if the user enters an invalid function name, you they get an error.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Modify the awk script with `sed`

You can store your awk script in a variable, and use sed to modify it before execution by awk.  e.g.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

awkscript='COL FN VAL'

col=8
fn='>'
val=2 

awk -f <(printf "%s" "$awkscript" |
           sed -e "s/COL/\$$col/; s/FN/$fn/; s/VAL/$val/") temp
```

This transforms "$awkscript" from `COL FN VAL` to `$8 > 2`.

In short, the "awk script" is a template where some hard-coded strings (`COL`, `FN`, and `VAL`) are replaced by variables.

Warning: this can break if any of the variables contain values (such as  `/`) that affect how the `sed` script is interpreted by `sed`.   There are safer, better, more complicated ways to do templating, but simple templating like this is OK if you can ensure that the variables will only ever hold compatible, non-sed-breaking values.

You could also use a file or a [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) to hold the awk script.

or, for a really simple implementation, something like:

```bash
awk -f <(echo "$col $fn $val") temp
```

or

```bash
awk -f <(cat <<< "$col $fn $val") temp
```

#### 2. Using `perl` and `eval`

You could do this with `perl` instead of awk, using the `eval` function.

```bash
perl -F, -slne 'print if (eval "$F[7] $fn $val")' -- -val="$value" -fn='>' temp
```

or even:

```bash
perl -F, -slne 'print if (eval "$F[$col-1] $fn $val")'  -- \
  -col=8 -val="$value" -fn='<' temp
```

Note that perl's arrays start from zero, so this uses `$F[7]` instead of $8 as would be used with `awk`.

perl's `-s` option turns on perl's awk-like ability to take variable assignments from the command line.

From `man perlrun`:

> **-s** enables rudimentary switch parsing for switches on the command line after
> the program name but before any filename arguments (or before an argument
> of `--`). Any switch found there is removed from `@ARGV` and sets the
> corresponding variable in the Perl program.  The following program prints
> "1" if the program is invoked with a -xyz switch, and "abc" if it is
> invoked with -xyz=abc.
>
> ```bash
>    #!/usr/bin/perl -s
>    if ($xyz) { print "$xyz\n" }
> ```

**WARNING:** `eval` is potentially dangerous.  Unless you strictly control what is allowed to be provided to `$fn`, the user can cause your script to run **any** perl code.

It would be **much** safer to allow the user to choose only from a limited, pre-defined set of operators.